# How to fast sum values in directed graph in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, directed-graph

I have a directed graph with like 2000 nodes stored in a file. Each line represents an edge from the node stored in the first column to the node stored in the second column, it is even easy to visualize the data for example in [dot(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dot). Columns are separated by tabs, rows separated by newlines and nodes are named with any of the `a-zA-Z0-9_` characters. Tree can have multiple roots, it may have cycles, which should be ignored. I don't care about cycles, they are redundant, but they can happen in the input. Below I am presenting an example of the graph, with `tr` to substitute spaces for tabs and here-document, to easy reproduce the input file:

```
tr ' ' '\t' <<EOF >connections.txt
str1 str2
str2 str3
str3 str4
str100 str2
str100 str101
str101 str102
EOF
```

I have also a list of some node in the graph, called heads. These will be the starting nodes, ie. heads:

```
tr ' ' '\t' <<EOF >heads.txt
str1
str100
EOF
```

And I have also a list of associated "cost" with each node. Example with some random data:

```
tr ' ' '\t' <<EOF >cost.txt
str1 1
str2 5
str3 10
str4 548
str100 57
str101 39
str102 23
EOF
```

I want to sum the "cost" of each node while traversing the tree from nodes stored in head.txt and print the cost with some traversing information for each leaf.

I want to:

- for each node in heads.txt

  - sum the cost from costs.txt of the node into some variable
  - find that node in connections.txt
  - find what does this node connect to
  - and repeat the algorithm for each of the nodes the node connects to
  - when the node is connected with nothing, print the sum of costs

Ideally the script would look like:

```
$ script.sh heads.txt connections.txt cost.txt
str1->str2->str3->str4    1+5+10+548   564
str100->str2->str3->str4  57+5+10+548  620
str100->str101->str102    57+39+23     119
```

And I even have written this, and it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

headsf=$1
connectionsf=$2
costf=$3


get_cost() {
    grep "^$1"$'\t' "$costf" | cut -f2 || echo 0
}

get_conn() {
    grep "^$1"$'\t' "$connectionsf" | cut -f2
}

check_conns() {
    grep -q "^$1"$'\t' "$connectionsf"
}

f_output() {
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$1" "$2"
}

f() {
    local func cost
    func="$1"
    cost=$(get_cost "$func")

    if ! check_conns "$func"; then
        f_output "${2:+$2->}$func" "${3:+$3+}$cost"
        return
    fi

    get_conn "$func" |
    while IFS=$'\t' read -r calls; do
        if [ "$func" = "$calls" ]; then
            echo "$func is recursive" >&2
            continue
        fi
        if <<<"$2" grep -q -w "$calls"; then
            printf "$2 calls recursive $calls\n" >&2
            continue
        fi

        f "$calls" "${2:+$2->}$func" "${3:+$3+}$cost"
    done
}

while IFS= read -r head; do
    f "$head" "" ""
done < "$headsf" |
while IFS=$'\t' read -r func calc; do
    tmp=$(<<<$calc bc)
    printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$func" "$calc" "$tmp"
done | 
column -t -s $'\t'
```

However it is impossibly slow on bigger inputs. Even with sample files here (only 6 lines) the script takes 200ms on my machine. How can I speed it up? Can the inputs be sorted, joined somehow to speed it up (grep doesn't care if the input is sorted)? Can this be done faster in awk or other unix tools?

I would like to limit myself to bash shell and standard *unix tools, coreutils, moreutils, datamash and such.  I tried doing it in awk, but failed, I have no idea how to do find something recursively in the input in `awk`. It this feels to me "doable" in a shell script really fast.

Comment: Real fast?  Properly not using bash, with large input files.  Python (and even Perl) are much faster than bash in general.  This is a case of "the right tool for the right job" IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since no one has posted an answer yet, here is an awk solution as a starting point:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  FS=OFS="\t"
}
FILENAME=="connections.txt" {
  edges[$1,++count[$1]]=$2
  next
}
FILENAME=="cost.txt" {
  costs[$1]=$2
  next
}
FILENAME=="heads.txt" {
  f($1)
}

function f(node,
    path,cost,sum,prev,sep1,sep2,i) {
  if(node in prev)
    # cycle detected
    return

  path=path sep1 node
  cost=cost sep2 costs[node]
  sum+=costs[node]

  if(!count[node]) {
    print path,cost,sum
  }
  else {
    prev[node]
    for(i=1;i<=count[node];++i)
      f(edges[node,i],path,cost,sum,prev,"->","+")
    delete prev[node]
  }
}
```

Make it read `connections.txt` and `cost.txt` before `heads.txt`.
Its output (padded):

```
$ awk -f tst.awk connections.txt cost.txt heads.txt
str1->str2->str3->str4     1+5+10+548     564
str100->str2->str3->str4   57+5+10+548    620
str100->str101->str102     57+39+23       119
```

Comment: Wow, this "starting point" works just right. And is very, very fast - takes ca. 100ms with over 2000 connections.txt and over 400 heads in heads.txt. awk just keeps to amaze me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You say you want only standard tools, but you also mention using `dot` on your data, so I'm assuming you have the other graphviz utilities available... in particular, `gvpr`, which is like `awk` for graphs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

graph=$(mktemp)

join -t$'\t' -j1 -o 0,1.2,2.2 -a2 \
     <(sort -k1,1 connections.txt) \
     <(sort -k1,1 cost.txt) |
    awk -F$'\t' 'BEGIN { print "digraph g {" }
         { printf "%s [cost = %d ]\n", $1, $3
           if ($2 != "") printf "%s -> %s\n", $1, $2  }
         END { print "}" }' > "$graph"

while read root; do
    gvpr -a "$root" '
BEGIN {
      int depth;
      int seen[string];
      string path[int];
      int costs[int];
}
BEG_G {
      $tvtype = TV_prepostfwd;
      $tvroot = node($, ARGV[0]);
}
N {
  if ($.name in seen) {
     depth--;
  } else {
    seen[$.name] = 1;
    path[depth] = $.name;
    costs[depth] = $.cost;
    depth++;
    if (!fstout($) && path[0] == ARGV[0]) {
       int i, c = 0;
       for (i = 0; i < depth - 1; i++) {
         printf("%s->", path[i]);
       }
       printf("%s\t", $.name);
       for (i = 0; i < depth - 1; i++) {
         c += costs[i];
         printf("%d+", costs[i]);
       }       
       c += $.cost;
       printf("%d\t%d\n", $.cost, c);
    }
  }
}' "$graph"
done < heads.txt

rm -f "$graph"
```

Running this after creating your data files:

```
$ ./paths.sh
str1->str2->str3->str4  1+5+10+548  564
str100->str2->str3->str4    57+5+10+548 620
str100->str101->str102  57+39+23    119
```

---

Or, since it's so ubiquitous it might as well be standard, a sqlite-based solution. This one doesn't even require bash/zsh/ksh93, unlike the above.

```
$ sqlite3 -batch -noheader -list <<EOF
.separator "\t"
CREATE TABLE heads(node TEXT);
.import heads.txt heads
CREATE TABLE costs(node TEXT PRIMARY KEY, cost INTEGER) WITHOUT ROWID;
.import cost.txt costs
CREATE TABLE connections(from_node TEXT, to_node TEXT
                       , PRIMARY KEY(from_node, to_node)) WITHOUT ROWID;
.import connections.txt connections
WITH RECURSIVE paths(tail, path, costs, cost) AS
 (SELECT h.node, h.node, c.cost, c.cost
  FROM heads AS h
  JOIN costs AS c ON h.node = c.node
  UNION ALL
  SELECT conn.to_node, p.path || '->' || conn.to_node
       , p.costs || '+' || c.cost, p.cost + c.cost
  FROM paths AS p
  JOIN connections AS conn ON conn.from_node = p.tail
  JOIN costs AS c ON c.node = conn.to_node
 )
SELECT path, costs, cost FROM paths AS p
WHERE tail NOT IN (SELECT from_node FROM connections)
ORDER BY path;
EOF
str1->str2->str3->str4  1+5+10+548  564
str100->str101->str102  57+39+23    119
str100->str2->str3->str4    57+5+10+548 620
```

Comment: Wow, great work! Thank you very, very much! So, just to let it know i tested it out,  and.. you have a repeated comma in `CREATE TABLE connections ... to_node TEXT, , PRIMARY KEY` ; ) . I will not have gvpr on target machine and anyway gvpr is way slower then sqlite3. sqlite3 looks amazing ("WITH RECURSIVE", wow). I needed to add a check so that it didn't enter endless loop on loops in the graph, I added a [where clause](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/InexperiencedSinfulFiber). And, to my suprise, sqlite is like 40ms slower then awk on my target training set. Great work!